# How to set common field with default value in each view in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am new to RubyOnRails
I want to set a common field for each view in ruby.

I am using Rails 4.0.0, I have set a global variable in controller.

```
VERSION = "1000"
```

I want to set a version field in each view.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@rebate, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :version %><br>
    <%= f.text_field, version, :html_input=>{:value=>ApplicationController::VERSION} %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I don't want to store this version field in database, but I want use this version field in each view. I want to check that value in controller while submitting the view. But I dont know how to set the common value for each view. For the above code I'm getting the error -

```
syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
```

Please help me, so that I can set common field in each view.

Comment: `VERSION = '1000'` doesn't set global variable, but constant.

Comment: then how can I set the version value so that I can access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= text_field_tag :version, ApplicationController::VERSION %>
```

Comment: After this I'm not getting any error, but it is not showing any value

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
## Notice comma after f.text_field that is causing error
<%= f.text_field, version, :html_input=>{:value=>ApplicationController::VERSION} %>
```

with

```
<%= f.text_field :version, :html_input=>{:value=>ApplicationController::VERSION} %>
```

By setting constant `VERSION` in `ApplicationController`, you would be able to access it in views,like the way you are doing.

Comment: I have tried this, but I'm getting the error "undefined method `version' for"

Comment: That's because you might not have a version field for your model `Rebate`. `simple_form_for` would think version is an attribute of rebate and try to set its value.

Comment: VERSION is a constant right. Why are you putting it in textfield, why not just display its value directly in a label or a <p> tag. Constants are not supposed to change.

Comment: I want user to enter the value, so I have given it as text_field

Comment: If its a changeable value then it should not be declared as a constant.Correct me if I am wrong, you want a global variable across the application which should be editable in all the views?